# How to return attributes from database

Tags: php

I have a problem.Take a look at my function. Explain to you everything in detail. The first one only returns 'front' or 'back' depending on which one is selected. I want that if none of this is selected, return me everything front and back in this format:

```
array (size=3)
  'breite' => string '110' (length=3)
  'hoehe' => string '70' (length=2)
  'zoll' => string '17' (length=2)
```

Look my URL:

```
 http://localhost/ccr/filter?atts[breite]=110&atts[hoehe]=70&atts[zoll]=17&parent=49
```

via url I send attibutes front or back.

I only need to via url , if front or back non selected return and front and back. Look my function code which you need:

```
    if(key_exists('antrieb',$get)) {
        $antrieb = $get['antrieb']; //back or front
        $query = $this->db->query("
            SELECT mo.$antrieb
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "model mo
            WHERE mo.id != 0
            $where
        ")->rows;
        $data = []; 
        $size = explode("|", $query[0][$antrieb]);
        $data['atts'] = array(
            'breite' => $size[0],
            'hoehe' => $size[1],
            'zoll' => $size[2]
        );
    }else {
        $query = $this->db->query("
            SELECT mo.front, mo.back
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "model mo
            WHERE mo.id != 0
            $where
        ")->rows;
                 var_dump($query); 
             (result this code is comment only for show you
                array (size=2)
                'front' => string '110|70|17' (length=9)
                'back' => string '130|70|17' (length=9)
                 )
         $size = explode("|", $query[0]);
               there is litle problem i need expolde front and back with |
        $data2 = [];
        $data2['atts'] = [
            'breite' => $size[0],
            'hoehe' => $size[1],
            'zoll' => $size[2]
        ];
         (resulte write only for you
              var_dump($data2);
              array (size=1)
          'atts' => 
             array (size=3)
                'breite' => null
                'hoehe' => null
                'zoll' => null
    }
          )
```

Look my column which i need get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO7Fm.jpg

This is just a part of a feature that has over 150 lines of code. I think that the problem lies here and that's why I show you that I would not write everything too big and you will not get it. if you have a question am here. If you want all function I show you. Front and is react.js but that is not important for now. Thanks